# Can't get a form to float to the right

Tags: html, css, forms, resize, css-float

For some reason a form on my website(a search box) won't float to the right like coded in css when on a mobile phone. However, it will float to the right when on a laptop or ipad. I've also had the same issue with getting a footer to actually be at the bottom of the page. I've tried float:right, right:0px, and I even tried setting it from the left 100%. What should I change? This is my CSS for mobile phones:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .body{ margin: 0px auto; width:250%; height:175%; padding:1%; }
    #h1 {font-size:1.3em; }
    #div2 ul li a {font-size:0.6em;}
    #forum {font-size:0.8em; }
    #form {font-size:0.6em;top : 125px;
    float:right; }
    #posts {font-size:0.6em;}
}
```

Here's the code they apply to

```
<body class = "body">
    <div id = "div2">
            <h1 id = "h1">Website</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href = "home.php"> Home </a></li>
                        <li class = "active"> <a href = "afe.php">webpage</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href = "ha.php">webpage</a> </li>
                        <li> <a href = "eaf.php">webpage</a></li>
                        <li> <a href = "list.php">list</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li> <a href = "af.php">webpage</a></li>
                                <li> <a href = "blah.php">webpage</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li> <a href = "try.php">webpage</a></li>
                        <li> <a href = "suggestions.php">Suggestions</a></li>
                    </ul>
    </div>
<h1 class = "header"> What are you thinking about?</h1>
<form action='afe.php' class = "forum" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <textarea name="postbody" rows="4" cols="60" class = "text"></textarea>
         <br />Upload an image:
        <input type="file" name="postimg">
        <input type="submit" name="post" value="Post">
</form>
```

Here's the search box

```
<div class = "form">
<form action="aef.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="searchbox" value="" class = "form-search-input" placeholder="Search....">
    <span><input type="submit" name="search" value=""></span> 
</form>
</div>

</body>
```

This web page is a forum so the posts class is where I display all the posts at the bottom of the page and the body class applies to the whole webpage. And here's the CSS for the footer that won't go to the bottom of the page: .end{font-size:0.8em;bottom:0px;}

Comment: One thing I notice is that your CSS targets an element with and *ID* of "form" (`#form`), but the HTML shows a *class* called "form" (`class="form"`). Same is true for `#forum`.

Comment: I just fixed that but it still floats to the left instead of the right

Comment: [I can't reproduce that](https://jsfiddle.net/hc2ak7Lo/). Can you edit your question to help demonstrate?